# A href remove all styling

Tags: html, css

I have a link with an `<IMG>` inside, which directs to a `target=_blank`, now what I need to do is remove the `purple` border that comes round the image after I click the link..

I used `text-decoration: none;` but it still appears ... any ideas? I didn't post the code as none is actually in place except

```
#portheader a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
}

<div id="portheader">
    <a href="http://www.myweb.com" target="_blank"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: @airi - "I didn't post the code as none is actually in place except"

Comment: edited, added some more information, but there isn't any more code.. its as simple as that :s

Comment: can you remove the #portheader and see what happen..

Comment: what you mean by border is the dotted line around the anchor tag?

Comment: Tried it on Chrome, and the selection doesn't appear, only on firefox it seems.

Comment: seem you not give us your image code as you said : purple' border that comes round the image after I click the link.. where the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this to your css

```
outline: 0;
```

Comment: [Don't do that](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200905/do_not_remove_the_outline_from_links_and_form_controls/)

Comment: No prob.

Maybe selecting this as the answer? thanks!

Comment: Grrr what do we use then :/

Comment: Its fine since its just for the keyboard. it would not just be selected when you try to navigate by "TAB" key

Answer (score 0):

Give border:none for the image in css

For the Old browsers, use border="0" in the img tag itself.

Comment: Didn't work still the same..

Comment: Don't do anything for "the Old browsers". Nobody uses browsers that old. We're talking IE 2 here, not IE 8 or even IE 6.